# Extending the Django 1.11 User Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication, django-users

I am attempting to work out how to extend the Django user model to add information to a user.  I can't seem to get it to work.  What am I doing wrong?
  Is it okay to have foreignkeys within the same model I am extending in to?  How do you create a superuser, or do you have to do it manually through the `python manage.py shell`?

Here's my code so far:

```
class PersonModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    phone = models.ForeignKey(PhoneModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s - %s - %s, %s' % (self.firstName, self.lastName,
                                        self.company, self.phone, self.email
                                       )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['firstName']
        verbose_name = "Customer Contact Information"
        #verbose_name_plural = "Contacts"

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        PersonModel.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

UPDATE (Final):
With the help of raratiru I've been able to mostly get the script he shared going.  I still struggle to create a super user because of my foreign key requirements.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser,
    PermissionsMixin,
    BaseUserManager,
)
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from customers import models as customers_models

class TravelModel(models.Model):
   mileageRate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)

   def __str__(self):
      return '%s' % (self.mileageRate)

   class Meta:
      verbose_name = "Current Federal Milage Rate"
      #verbose_name_plural = "Milage"


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, firstName, lastName, company, phone, password=None, **kwargs):
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **kwargs)
        user.firstName = firstName
        user.lastName = lastName
        user.company = company
        user.phone = phone
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, firstName, lastName, password=None, **kwargs):
        #user = self.create_user(**kwargs)
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **kwargs)
        user.firstName = firstName
        user.lastName = lastName
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class AliasField(models.Field):
    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name, virtual_only=False):
        super().contribute_to_class(cls, name, virtual_only=True)
        setattr(cls, name, self)

    def __get__(self, instance, instance_type=None):
        return getattr(instance, self.db_column)


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
      firstName = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
      lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
      company = models.ForeignKey(customers_models.CompanyModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
      phone = models.ForeignKey(customers_models.PhoneModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)

      email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=255, unique=True)

      is_staff = models.BooleanField(
            _('staff status'),
            default=False,
            help_text=_(
                  'Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                  'site.'
            )
      )
      is_active = models.BooleanField(
            _('active'),
            default=True,
            help_text=_(
                  'Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                  'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
            )
      )
      username = AliasField(db_column='email')

      objects = UserManager()

      USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
      REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['firstName','lastName',]

      class Meta(object):
            ordering = ['firstName']
            verbose_name = _('Contact')
            verbose_name_plural = _('Contacts')

      def __str__(self):
            return '%s - %s %s - %s - %s' % (self.company, self.firstName, self.lastName, self.email, self.phone)

      def get_full_name(self):
            return self.email

      def get_short_name(self):
            return self.email

      def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
            """
            Sends an email to this User.
            """
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

To circumvent the foreignkey struggles, the easiest solution is to remove the null=False requirement before creating the superuser - assign a company and phone after - and set null back to false afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I extended my user model. The following code also substitutes the username for an email field. I am posting it because it causes core changes so it makes clear the logic behind.

The base idea can be found and explained in [this post](https://medium.com/@ramykhuffash/django-authentication-with-just-an-email-and-password-no-username-required-33e47976b517). A very nice post can also be found [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html).

The AliasField in this case, creates the field `username` as an alias to `email`. Although this is not necessary given that django has documented the [proper way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) of finding the user model and its relevant fields.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser,
    PermissionsMixin,
    BaseUserManager,
)
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **kwargs)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, **kwargs):
        user = self.create_user(**kwargs)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class AliasField(models.Field):
    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name, private_only=False):
        super().contribute_to_class(cls, name, private_only=True)
        setattr(cls, name, self)

    def __get__(self, instance, instance_type=None):
        return getattr(instance, self.db_column)


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    custom_field = models.ForeignKey(
        'app.Model',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )

    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=255, unique=True)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
            'site.'
        )
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as '
            'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        )
    )
    username = AliasField(db_column='email')

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user_branch_key', ]

    class Meta(object):
        ordering = ['email']
        verbose_name = _('My User')
        verbose_name_plural = _('My User')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'id: {0} - {1}, {2}'.format(self.id, self.email, self.user_branch_key)

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Sends an email to this User.
        """
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

Once you extend your user model, for example inside the application with the name `the_user` in the file `./the_user/models.py` you have to make some changes in the `settings.py` file:

- Register the application in the `INSTALLED_APPS`
- `./manage.py makemigrations` && `./manage.py migrate`
- Set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'the_user.MyUser` as described in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

This way, in another model you can add a foreignkey as follows:

```
from the_user.models import MyUser
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class AModel(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_user'
    )
```

Comment: Seems like rather than extending, you're rewriting the django user model.  That's a hell of a lot more elaborate than the Django docs on this subject :(

Comment: @Jaberwocky Indeed. I was searching for the code to make core changes (use email instead of the username) and the above illustrates the logic behind the user model.

Comment: I appreciate your contribution.  I feel like this doesn't answer my question fully though.  Can you, and if so, how do you tie in foreign key relationships to the user?

More elaborately, if I wanted to store what I have in `PersonModel`, how can that be done using your method?

Comment: I found the rest of my answers in 
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model I believe.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jaberwocky Yes indeed. You can also add your model as an inline to the existing user admin instead of rewriting it as I did. I have updated my answer to illustrate how you can add foreign keys.

Comment: Please do, that's the most critical part of this for me.

Comment: what is `user_branch_key = models.ForeignKey(
        'ellas.Municipality',...`?

Comment: @Jaberwocky It is a custom field nothing more. It could be `phone = models.ForeignKey(PhoneModel, ...`

Comment: Right, so isn't this where I would add fields to the user (incl. foreign keys)?  Then tack them back up at the top in the create_user methods?

Comment: @Jaberwocky Yes, there you can add all the fields of the `PersonModel` except the `OneToOneField`.

Comment: The OneToOne field was just my attempt at extending the built in user model :)

Comment: @Jaberwocky Yes a good attempt, which can be useful if you attach it as an inline to the existing user model. But sometimes it is a better and more robust solution to have it all together in one place.

Comment: So when you foreignkey something, how do you create a superuser from a fresh environment?  For example in the model I posted, there is no company or phone at the time of initial migration.

Comment: @Jaberwocky According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.REQUIRED_FIELDS), any field that is not null or blank, should be included in the `REQUIRED_FIELDS`. Of course, the fields you have created have `null=True` therefore they will be empty and they have to be manually filled.

Comment: Sorry, again, that's old.  I'm running off of your script now.  I do have those items in required fields.  I'll update.  When I go to create a superuser, it askes me for a company ID.  Obviously there are no companies yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158778/discussion-between-jaberwocky-and-raratiru).